# How to import and convert?

Tags: python, converters

After importing file, opening and reading it

```
fop = open('lottery.txt','r')
_str = fop.read()
fop.close()
```

I'm getting such content:

```
'   monday: 2 23\ntuesday :4 31\nwednesday   : 19 22\nthursday : 1'
```

How can I convert it to dictionary and get as result this:

```
{'monday': '2 23', 'tuesday': '4 31','wednesday': '19 22', 'thursday' : '1'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process it line by line:

```
with open('lottery.txt', 'r') as fop:
    result = dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1)) for line in fop)
```

The `dict(map(..) for line in fop)` is using a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions); we loop over `fop` per line, then split that line into two values on the first `:` colon we find, and store the stripped results of that as key and value of a mapping.

The `map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))` removes whitespace from the start and end of each part of the split line. The `.split()` itself limits the split on `:` to 1 such character only, to prevent any extra `:` colon on the line from confusing the `dict` constructor, which only wants `(key, value)` pairs.

Demo:

```
>>> open('/tmp/lottery.txt', 'w').write('   monday: 2 23\ntuesday :4 31\nwednesday   : 19 22\nthursday : 1')
>>> with open('/tmp/lottery.txt', 'r') as fop:
...     result = dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1)) for line in fop)
... 
>>> result
{'tuesday': '4 31', 'thursday': '1', 'wednesday': '19 22', 'monday': '2 23'}
```

The long, non-generator expression version would be:

```
with open('lottery.txt', 'r') as fop:
    result = {}
    for line in fop:
        key, value = line.split(':', 1)
        result[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

Comment: @wim: missed the 1 key and hit `'` instead (Dvorak keyboard).

Comment: trying ur code im getting such error: `there's an error in your program: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: @user1768615: yes, there was a typo in it.

Comment: I'd give you a +1 on the dvorak keyboard alone.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: except that my trick with the loop over split results doesn't work at all. :-P Corrected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters now everything is working properly, could u be so kind and explain me each step please?

Comment: hey!  i use dvorak too.  aoeui !!

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there any other way to get such result without using generator expression?

Comment: @user1768615: sure, use a `for` loop over the `fop` object to process each line separately. A generator expression is just a compact loop. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: so legends are true, ninja's are rly fast ^^ thanks you for help!